# Vaadin 7 project won't load in version 8

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin8

I developed a web app two years ago with Vaadin 7 and now I'm trying to run it with the latest plugin for Eclipse. The main servlet is asking me to implement some new methods, which seem to be important, and the thing won't load.

[image]

Comment: **1)** What's the actual question, how to [migrate from 7 to 8](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html)? **2)** The error popup does not say anything about the servlet, it clearly states that `TimeinUI must implement ... SerializableTypeOracle.xxx()`, but we can't see the definition of the UI class in your screenshot.

Comment: You need to post the actual code and error messages (if any) in the question itself

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the migration guide for a upgrade from vaadin 7 to vaadin 8.

[Migration to vaadin 8](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/migration/migrating-to-vaadin8.html)

In short you have to change your pom.xml from

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
  <version>7.7.6</version>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
  <artifactId>vaadin-compatibility-server</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

If you used one of the deprecated themese (Reindeer, Runo, Chameleon, Base) you have to add the vaadin-compatibility-themes dependency too.

As last step you have to change the imports to match the compatibility packages.
You can either do it manually, or use [this migration tool](https://github.com/vaadin/framework8-migration-tool) to handle it for you.

If you have own client side widgets, then you will need to upgrade these too.